# Python Pandas: Doing loop for every file in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

***So I have code which works for one particular file in directory.

I want to make a loop which will do the following but for every .csv file in directory

1) Open file 2) Add one column 3) Save file to new location

My code***

```
import pandas as pd  
import os  
import glob 

plik = pd.read_csv('C:\Python\zrodlo\CSCO.csv', delimiter=";")  
plik['Change'] = ((plik['Close'] - plik['Open'])/plik['Open']*100)  
plik.to_csv('C:\Python\zrodlo\csv_nowe_pliki\ew_file.csv')
```

**Lines which might come in handy for the loop. I did not know how to make good use of them**

````
os.chdir('C:\Python\zrodlo')  
print(os.getcwd())  

for filename in os.listdir('C:\Python\zrodlo'):  
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):  
        print(filename)   

2)  
path = "C:\Python\zrodlo\*.csv"  
for fname in glob.glob(path):  
    print(fname)```
````

**Thank you for your input**

**EDIT, Question is what to put into last line for loop to save multiple files?**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

path = "C:\Python\zrodlo\*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)
    plik = pd.read_csv(fname, delimiter=";")
    plik['Change'] = ((plik['Close'] - plik['Open']) / plik['Open'] * 100)
    plik.to_csv('C:\Python\zrodlo\csv_nowe_pliki\ew_file.csv')
```

***EDIT, SOLUTION***

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

os.chdir('C:\Python\zrodlo')
print(os.getcwd())
for filename in os.listdir('C:\Python\zrodlo'):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        print(filename)
        plik = pd.read_csv('C:\Python\zrodlo\\'+filename, delimiter=";")
        plik['Change'] = ((plik['Close'] - plik['Open'])/plik['Open']*100)
        os.chdir('C:\Python\zrodlo\csv_nowe_pliki')
        plik.to_csv(filename)
        os.chdir('C:\Python\zrodlo')
```

Comment: Looks like you have all the pieces. Can you elaborate on what issue you are having?

Comment: I am not to sure what to put into plik.to_csv function for my loop to save multiple files.  
My idea is to put sth like:  
    plik = pd.read_csv(fname, delimiter=";")  
    plik['Change'] = ((plik['Close'] - plik['Open']) / plik['Open'] * 100)  
    plik.to_csv('C:\Python\zrodlo\csv_nowe_pliki\??.csv')

Comment: look up python string formatting and use that to change the file name each time through the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd  
import os  
import glob 

os.chdir('C:\Python\zrodlo')  
print(os.getcwd())  

for filename in os.listdir('C:\Python\zrodlo'):  
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):  
        print(filename)   
        plik = pd.read_csv('C:\Python\zrodlo\'+filename, delimiter=";")  
        plik['Change'] = ((plik['Close'] - plik['Open'])/plik['Open']*100)
        # You need to change the filename below otherwise you are rewriting every time after you created it
        plik.to_csv(glob.glob("C:\Python\zrodlo\csv_nowe_pliki\ew_file.csv"))
```

Comment: `'C:\Python\zrodlo\'` must be `'C:\Python\zrodlo\\'`.

Comment: I wonder why plik.to_csv(glob.glob('C:\Python\zrodlo\csv_nowe_pliki\\'+filename))
does not work, if it works with reading it shouldn't be the same with saving files?

Comment: I found the way around, new solution in original post.